# Comparing two lists by object fields

Tags: java

I have two lists of Student objects. A student object is as follows:

```
Student
int id
int class id
String name
int age
```

In one list, I have student objects with the classId, name and age fields populated. I then insert them into a database which returns a collection of those same objects with the id populated with the integer assigned by the db schema. I wish to equate these two lists as best as possible to ensure the db operation was successful. I can think of two ways to do this. Either equate all student objects in the input list and output lists using all fields except id. Or, manually injecting the id of each student in the input list with the output list's values. Both ways are pretty unclean in their implementation so I was hoping there was a clean way to do it? For example, in the first option I can sort both the input and output collections, then iterate the first collection and compare with an index into the output collection for each field.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The database returns the same objects you inserted, but with the ID populated, yes? Why can't you use that list?

Comment: @cricket_007 How do i compare the list of objects going in (without id) with the list of objects coming out (with id)?

Comment: You could define your own `Comparator`, but still, I don't exactly see the need to compare them at all

Answer (score 1):

You can make your Student override the `.equals(Object o)` method.

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private int classId;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (age != other.age)
            return false;
        if (classId != other.classId)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

Then you can compare two students like so:

```
Student s1 = ...;
Student s2 = ...;

if(s1.equals(s2)) {
   //Do this when they are equal
}
```

This is a clean way to check for equality and all of Java's functions will call this overrided equals method. You can also use it with lists.

```
List<Student> studentList = ...;
Student s1 = ...;

if(studentList.contains(s1)) {
   //Do this when s1 is in the list
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: One caveat being the Student object is being used elsewhere for equality and therefore I cannot touch the equals method already defined to compare all fields for it

Comment: I see, is your goal validation? Meaning, are you writing an integrated test to insert into the database, and then select to confirm that the insertion worked?

Comment: Yep thats exactly my goal

Comment: Ok, either of your solutions sound fine to me. I know it's kinda ugly to do a chain of if, else ifs using the getters for Student, but I can't think of a better way. I don't think it's worth changing any other classes for a test case. I generally like to make my tests ugly as opposed to adding code to my tested classes to make the tests slicker, and the tested classes uglier.

You could add another equals method with a different name that tests the non-id fields.

Comment: Actually, what I would do is just add function to your test that takes two Students and compares them on the non-id fields: private boolean areStudentsEqual(Student s1, Student s2)

Comment: I was playing around with using something like Comparing.().thenComparing() but cant get the syntax/method quite right

Comment: Just use Objects.equals it's built into to Java and is way cleaner.